# Calling alias_method from an ActionController, NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3 I'm trying to call `alias_method` from my `before_filter` but I'm getting this error: `NoMethodError in MyController#index`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :my_test

  protect_from_forgery
  helper :all

  def my_test
      debugger
      alias_method :new_method_name, :old_method_name
  end
end
```

From the debugger:

```
(rdb:3) p self.methods.grep /old_method_name/
["old_method_name"]
```

Comment: Whoever thumbed-down this question, please explain why you did this.

Comment: You're going to have to provide us with more information than simply an error message. The code that you're using would be a great start.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the answer. Whether or not this a good idea or not, I'd like to hear what you have to say...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :my_test

  protect_from_forgery
  helper :all

  def my_test
      self.class_eval("alias_method :new_method_name, :old_method_name")
  end
end
```